# A pronoun/possessive adjective in a complex construction

Tags: pronouns, possessives

"I had been warned about Bill by Dave, and I'd seen his explosive temper in action."

Is the antecedent of the possessive adjective 'his' clear here? Or is there some ambiguity as to whether it refers to Bill or Dave?

Oh, and quick addition: If I made it "I had been warned by Dave about Bill, and I'd seen his explosive temper in action", would that make a difference?

Comment: The natural reading here is to consider the warning and temper to be about the same person.

Comment: Okay, but is that only because of 'warned' and 'temper'? If I said, "I had been warned about Bill by Dave, and I'd been texted by him several times" would the 'natural reading' seem so clear?

Comment: The context is sometimes strong enough to sway what would otherwise be ambiguous. In the case of your question's example, that's due to the assumed link between *warning* to *temper*. In your comment's example, *warned* and *texted* suggest an activity-means link, biasing the interpretation of the word *him*.

Comment: So are you saying it IS ambiguous? Given that both Bill and Dave are objects of prepositions, and neither is a subject or direct object, it does seem ambiguous to me. But perhaps there is some grammatical rule to disambiguate it?

Comment: Lawrence explained it as not being ambiguous in context. If you keep trying to find ambiguity, you are not far from finding it. In such a case, you need to throw in the named subject a second time to clear it up (the ambiguity, not the subject or the time).

Comment: Yes, but there is context and there are grammatical rules. If I say, "Bill thought about Ted. He rang him." there is no ambiguity because 'Bill' is the subject. If we talk purely in terms of grammatical rules, is there a rule-based way of determining who 'his' in my example refers to? It seems you are saying there is not.